# SQL PIVOT oddity: Why do the result columns show same data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've set up a PIVOT in SQL and despite following the syntax to a 't', my output is oriented oddly.

Specifically, I have 36 'pivoted' columns and one additional date column.  I'd like to show entries for each column for a given date but instead I'm seeing 36 of the same date, with one non-NULL entry for each column, a bit like an identity matrix.

Code here:

```
SELECT pvt.date ,
[COLUMN LIST]
FROM (  ...[subquery removed due to length]... ) AS source
PIVOT 
(
SUM(totalret)
FOR description IN (
[COLUMN LIST] )
    ) AS pvt

    order by date
```

Comment: It looks ok... but pivots are pretty tricky. It owuld help if you could post more info, sucy as before/after data sets, and a more detailed query. Does it still fail if you only specify four columns? If so, could you post the code (and before/after data) with those four columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being related to the column list within the sub-query (that I omitted).

I was selecting extraneous columns in the subquery that weren't being referenced or used directly in the pivot--removing them and leaving only those referenced in the pivot ended up fixing things.